# WebResponse Avoid Getting Binary Response From SOAP Web Service

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, http, soap

I'm invoking a SOAP web service with a C# application. The problem is that the response I'm recieving is binary not text (as it should be), I tried invoking from SoapUI and the response is text/xml, I also made a Wireshark capture (while testing from C# application) and it showed that (eXtensible Markup Language tab) the response is in fact text/xml.

```
string RequestTemplate = "XML REQUEST....";
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(URL));
request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate");
request.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "THEACTION");
request.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=utf-8";
request.Host = "1.2.3.4";
request.KeepAlive = true;
request.Timeout = 1000000000;
request.Accept = "text/xml";
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentLength = RequestTemplate.Length;
request.Expect = "";
request.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate (Object obj, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors errors)
{
    return true;
};
ServicePointManager.MaxServicePointIdleTime = 100000;

using (Stream stm = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    using (StreamWriter stmw = new StreamWriter(stm))
    {
        stmw.Write(RequestTemplate);
    }
}
using (StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
{
    string resultString = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
    Console.WriteLine(resultString);
}
```

UPDATE:
An example of the response: http://pastebin.com/iNjEKnuy 
Response headers: http://pastebin.com/ZH1UQu3X

Comment: Please add example of what your response and response headers looks like and exception/stacktrace. Drop the `GetRequestStream` and just try getting response.

Comment: @MikkoViitala If I drop the GetRequestStream how will I post xml data ?

Comment: Commented before reading it closely, just like before... :)

Comment: Looked at your edits. This makes no sense to me... w/o testing against actual service, which is not an option?

Comment: In the other question you asked why I suggested to get the request stream and I replied that it may be needed to write data to the service (I admit that it was not the other guy's case and I could have paid attention). But here is a good example of getting the request stream and writing in it because I'm dealing with a SOAP service that needs XML request. And the service is in a LAN.